# LIKE search on TEXT datatype

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I tried searching in questions, but unable to find.

I need to run MYSQL LIKE statement on a column whose datatype is TEXT
I am unable to do so, can anyone provide me sample query on it ?

```
tblTable Structure
===============
id int primary key
Subject Text
```

Now query is `select * from tblTable where Subject Like '%ABC%'`

Its not working, any help ?

Comment: is there any row in your `tblTable` where `Subject` has text ABC? show the text you are willing to get with this query

Comment: Works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b928d/1

Comment: I don't see any error in the query you have posted..

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, thanks for the fiddle link, its working there, don't know why didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tblTable ` WHERE MATCH(Subject) AGAINST('ABC' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I think this will work for you

Comment: I got this error:The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes: SELECT * FROM tblTable WHERE MATCH(Subject) AGAINST('ABC' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Comment: @ Garth Sebastian you have to change subject data type from text to fulltext